# How to add on or sum up earlier values based on a condition?

Tags: r

I have the following intraday data for 300 users and would like to find out the (i) maximum continuous steps taken by each user, and (ii) maximum continuous time spent walking. Continuous steps is defined as >70 steps per minute for this analysis.

The following is an excerpt of the dataframe (df).

| StudyID | Date | Time | Steps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-03-22 | 00:01:00 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-03-22 | 00:02:00 | 72 |
| 1234 | 2022-03-22 | 00:03:00 | 85 |
| 1234 | 2022-03-22 | 00:04:00 | 76 |
| 1234 | 2022-03-22 | 00:05:00 | 0 |

I was trying to obtain a column containing cumulative continuous steps (CulContSteps) and then planned to do a "group_by" and then find the max value.
The following table illustrates what I hoped to achieve.

| StudyID | Date | Time | Steps | continuousCheck | CulContSteps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-03-22 | 00:01:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-03-22 | 00:02:00 | 72 | 1 | 72 |
| 1234 | 2022-03-22 | 00:03:00 | 85 | 1 | 157 |
| 1234 | 2022-03-22 | 00:04:00 | 76 | 1 | 233 |
| 1234 | 2022-03-22 | 00:05:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Using the above example, the user with StudyID 1234 would then have maximum continuous steps of 233 and maximum continuous time of 3 minutes.

I have tried the following code but they do not work (I have ~2million records and when I run they just run continuously/hang) and am at my wits' end. Will greatly appreciate any advice / suggestion possible ways I could achieve the above. My deepest thanks in advance. Thanks!

```
df$CulContSteps=0

for (r in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
  r=r+1
  
  if (df$Date[r]==df$Date[r-1] & df$continuousCheck[r]==1){
    df$CulContSteps[r] = df$Steps[r] + df$CulContSteps[r-1]
  }
  else if (df$continuousCheck == 1) {
    df$CulContSteps[r] = df$Steps[r]
  }
  else {df$CulContSteps[r]=0}
}
```

The following code generates a sample df as illustrated in the above table.

```
df <- data.frame(StudyID = c(rep("1234",10), rep("5678", 10)),
                 Date = rep("2022-03-23", 20),
                 Time = rep(c("00:01:00",
                          "00:02:00",
                          "00:03:00",
                          "00:04:00",
                          "00:05:00",
                          "00:06:00",
                          "00:07:00",
                          "00:08:00",
                          "00:09:00",
                          "00:10:00"),2),
                 Steps = c(0,72,85,76,0,115,98,0,0,88,
                           71,72,0,0,81,89,64,0,80,99)
)
```

Comment: Hi. Start by giving programmatically some example data, i.e. some R code that generates your `df`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, have included as suggested. Thanks!

Comment: You say user with StudyID 1234 would have max continuous steps of 253 but your example suggests 233.  Where does the extra 20 come from?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "maximum". Suppose that the user has another continuous set of records at minutes 6-8. Would the maximum continuous time be 6 (the count of all rows marked "continuous"), or does the presence of a non-continuous row at minute 5 reset the counters, making the max time 3?

Comment: @stomper Thanks for highlighting the typo, should be 233. Have made the edits in the post.

Comment: @jdobres Thanks for clarifying. The latter scenario is the case, i.e. a non-continuous row resets the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a **tidyverse** solution. First let's ensure that your data are sorted by time (this may be time consuming for 2 million records, so if you are certain that your data are already sorted, you can skip this step). Then we determine the start of an "epoch", or a run of rows where `Steps > 70`, and use this to create a series of groupings per user. Finally, we summarize the metrics per epoch and return the maximum per user.

I prefer this approach because there is only one use of `cumsum`, and as a bonus, the end result also returns the label of the epoch with the most steps.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  group_by(StudyID) %>% 
  mutate(
    datetime = ymd_hms(paste(Date, Time)),
    contCheck = Steps > 70
  ) %>% 
  arrange(StudyID, datetime) %>% 
  mutate(
    start_of_epoch = (row_number() == 1 & contCheck) | (contCheck & lag(!contCheck | is.na(contCheck))),
    epoch = ifelse(contCheck, cumsum(start_of_epoch), NA)
  ) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(epoch)) %>% 
  group_by(StudyID, epoch) %>% 
  summarize(
    CulContSteps = sum(Steps),
    ContTime = sum(contCheck)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(StudyID, desc(CulContSteps)) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 1)

  StudyID epoch CulContSteps ContTime
  <chr>   <int>        <dbl>    <int>
1 1234        1          233        3
2 5678        3          179        2
```

Comment: Thanks very much @jdobres for your taking the time to understand the problem and to come up with the solution, and even explained on the approach. Have tried the code on both the sample and actual data and it works perfectly. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this fixes the issue.

Created a date/time variable to check for date/time continuity. You'll want to ensure you sort by StudyID and date/time. Uses the lag() to look back to determine continuity of StudyID and date/time.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)



df %>%
    mutate(dt = ymd_hms(paste(Date, Time)),
           cont = ifelse(StudyID == lag(StudyID)  & dt - lag(dt) == 1 & !Steps < 70 |
                         !StudyID == lag(StudyID) & !Steps < 70 ,1,0),
           cumSteps  = with(., ave(Steps, cumsum(cont == 0 | !StudyID == lag(StudyID)), FUN  = cumsum)),
           cumTime  = with(., ave(cont, cumsum(cont == 0 | !StudyID == lag(StudyID)), FUN  = cumsum))) %>%
    group_by(StudyID) %>%
    summarise(maxSteps = max(cumSteps), maxTime = max(cumTime))

   StudyID       Date     Time Steps                  dt cont cumSteps cumTime
1     1234 2022-03-23 00:01:00     0 2022-03-23 00:01:00    0        0       0
2     1234 2022-03-23 00:02:00    72 2022-03-23 00:02:00    1       72       1
3     1234 2022-03-23 00:03:00    85 2022-03-23 00:03:00    1      157       2
4     1234 2022-03-23 00:04:00    76 2022-03-23 00:04:00    1      233       3
5     1234 2022-03-23 00:05:00     0 2022-03-23 00:05:00    0        0       0
6     1234 2022-03-23 00:06:00   115 2022-03-23 00:06:00    1      115       1
7     1234 2022-03-23 00:07:00    98 2022-03-23 00:07:00    1      213       2
8     1234 2022-03-23 00:08:00     0 2022-03-23 00:08:00    0        0       0
9     1234 2022-03-23 00:09:00     0 2022-03-23 00:09:00    0        0       0
10    1234 2022-03-23 00:10:00    88 2022-03-23 00:10:00    1       88       1
11    5678 2022-03-23 00:01:00    71 2022-03-23 00:01:00    1       71       1
12    5678 2022-03-23 00:02:00    72 2022-03-23 00:02:00    1      143       2
13    5678 2022-03-23 00:03:00     0 2022-03-23 00:03:00    0        0       0
14    5678 2022-03-23 00:04:00     0 2022-03-23 00:04:00    0        0       0
15    5678 2022-03-23 00:05:00    81 2022-03-23 00:05:00    1       81       1
16    5678 2022-03-23 00:06:00    89 2022-03-23 00:06:00    1      170       2
17    5678 2022-03-23 00:07:00    64 2022-03-23 00:07:00    0       64       0
18    5678 2022-03-23 00:08:00     0 2022-03-23 00:08:00    0        0       0
19    5678 2022-03-23 00:09:00    80 2022-03-23 00:09:00    1       80       1
20    5678 2022-03-23 00:10:00    99 2022-03-23 00:10:00    1      179       2

  StudyID maxSteps maxTime
  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1234         233       3
2 5678         179       2
```

Comment: Thanks very much @stomper for responding so readily. You were the first to respond and even went on to improve the code following some clarifications. Thanks very much for your help and appreciate greatly! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` approach that may work fast.

First, create `continuousCheck` where `Steps` is greater than threshold, like 70.

Then, you can add `culContSteps` as the cumulative sum of `Steps`, grouped by a running counter based on `StudyID` and where `continuousCheck` is 0. That will cause this cumulative sum to reset when `Steps` falls below 70 (and `continuousCheck` is 0). `rleid` is useful to create this grouping running counter.

Then, you can calculate the number of continuous minutes by `StudyID` where the `continuousCheck` is 1. Again, `rleid` is useful here, to group together where `continuousCheck` is 1 in sequence.

The final steps summarize the maximum for steps and time. Note that you can remove the last bracketed expression in the chain if you want to see intermediate steps and calculations.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, continuousCheck := +(Steps > 70)][
  , culContSteps := cumsum(Steps), by = rleid(StudyID, continuousCheck == 0)][
    , .(.N, StudyID, culContSteps, continuousCheck), by = .(StudyID, rleid(continuousCheck == 1))][
      , .(maxContSteps = max(culContSteps), maxContTime = max(N)), by = StudyID
    ]
```

**Output**

```
   StudyID maxContSteps maxContTime
1:    1234          233           3
2:    5678          179           2
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben for the solution! Appreciate greatly!

Answer (score 0):

This approach will work on a time series with any number of days for each ID and with missing records.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

#Order the rows
df <- df[with(df, order(StudyID, Date, hms(Time))),]

#Fill the gaps of missing records for each StudyID
# (more than one minute difference between two consecutive rows)
df_full <- df %>%
  group_by(StudyID, Date)%>%
  summarise(Time=format(seq(min(as.Date(hms(Time), origin = Date)),
                            max(as.Date(hms(Time), origin = Date)),
                            by="1 min"), '%H:%M:%S'))
df <- merge(df, df_full, all.y = T)
df$Steps[is.na(df$Steps)] <- 0

#Generate an ID to differentiate between 1. StudyID and 2. Date within StudyID
df$continuousCheck <- as.numeric(paste0(1+as.numeric(factor(df$StudyID))%%2,
                            as.numeric(factor(df$Date))))
#Consider Steps above 70 only
df$continuousCheck[df$Steps <= 70] <- 0

#For each continuous Steps, calculate the 1. cumulative sum of the steps
# and 2. the time in minutes
rle_continuousCheck <- rle(df$continuousCheck)
df$CulContSteps <- NA
df$CulContTime <- NA
index = 0
df[,c("CulContSteps", "CulContTime")] <- do.call("rbind", sapply(rle_continuousCheck$lengths,
                                 FUN = function(x){
  current_indices=index+c(1:x)
  index <<- current_indices[length(current_indices)]
  res1 <- cumsum(df$Steps[current_indices])
  res2 <- c(1:length(current_indices))
  cbind(res1,res2)
}))
df$CulContSteps[df$continuousCheck==0] <- NA
df$CulContTime[df$continuousCheck==0] <- NA
```

Which results in:

```
df
#    StudyID       Date     Time Steps continuousCheck CulContSteps CulContTime
# 1     1234 2022-03-23 00:01:00     0               0           NA          NA
# 2     1234 2022-03-23 00:02:00    72              21           72           1
# 3     1234 2022-03-23 00:03:00    85              21          157           2
# 4     1234 2022-03-23 00:04:00    76              21          233           3
# 5     1234 2022-03-23 00:05:00     0               0           NA          NA
# 6     1234 2022-03-23 00:06:00   115              21          115           1
# 7     1234 2022-03-23 00:07:00    98              21          213           2
# 8     1234 2022-03-23 00:08:00     0               0           NA          NA
# 9     1234 2022-03-23 00:09:00     0               0           NA          NA
# 10    1234 2022-03-23 00:10:00    88              21           88           1
# 11    5678 2022-03-23 00:01:00    71              11           71           1
# 12    5678 2022-03-23 00:02:00    72              11          143           2
# 13    5678 2022-03-23 00:03:00     0               0           NA          NA
# 14    5678 2022-03-23 00:04:00     0               0           NA          NA
# 15    5678 2022-03-23 00:05:00    81              11           81           1
# 16    5678 2022-03-23 00:06:00    89              11          170           2
# 17    5678 2022-03-23 00:07:00    64               0           NA          NA
# 18    5678 2022-03-23 00:08:00     0               0           NA          NA
# 19    5678 2022-03-23 00:09:00    80              11           80           1
# 20    5678 2022-03-23 00:10:00    99              11          179           2
```

Then the maximum number of continuous steps and time walking for each user would be obtained with:

```
df %>%
  group_by(StudyID)%>%
  summarise(maxContSteps=max(CulContSteps, na.rm = TRUE),
            maxContTime=max(CulContTime, na.rm = TRUE))

#   StudyID maxContSteps maxContTime
#   <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 1234             233           3
# 2 5678             179           2
```

---

To produce a more complete dataset:

```
set.seed(123456)
df <- data.frame(StudyID = sort(rep(c(1:100),100)),
                 Date = rep(c(rep(as.Date('2020/01/01'),50), 
                              rep(as.Date('2020/01/02'),50)),
                            length.out = 10000),
                 Time = rep(format(seq(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:01:00", tz="GMT"),
                                       as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:50:00", tz="GMT"),
                                       by="1 min"), '%H:%M:%S'),
                            length.out = 10000),
                 Steps = sample(c(1:100), 10000, 
                                prob = c(1:100),
                                replace = T),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df <- df[sample(c(1:10000), 5000),]

head(df)

#      StudyID       Date     Time Steps
# 7144      72 2020-01-01 00:44:00    55
# 3060      31 2020-01-02 00:10:00    90
# 2382      24 2020-01-02 00:32:00    33
# 5078      51 2020-01-02 00:28:00     9
# 5818      59 2020-01-01 00:18:00    67
# 5371      54 2020-01-02 00:21:00    75
```

Comment: Thanks very much @marcguery for the solution and for the code for the more complete dataset! Appreciate greatly! :)